# C code doesn't print whole paragraph with newlines

Tags: c, char

This is my C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int c = getchar();
  while (c != EOF) {
    if (c != '\n')
      putchar(c);
    else putchar(32);
    c = getchar();
    }
return 0;
}
```

I want to make a program that prints out a paragraph with newlines, by replacing the `\n` character with spaces. The problem is, it only prints out the last line, when I use the code provided above.

For, example, for the text:

```
This is
my
text
```

the result printed is `text`.
The paragraph is properly printed when I remove the `if(), else` conditions, and only leave the `putchar()`, without trying to replace anything.

What's the problem?

Comment: Don't hard-code ASCII codes, use `putchar(' ')` to print a space.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for the advice. Will consider doing that!

Comment: Your file has carriage return characters in it.

Comment: You should skip them by checking for `'\r'`

Comment: Or use the `dos2unix` program to remove them from the file.

Comment: @Barmar still, when I replace '\n' with '\r', it prints the entire text, without replacing the carriage return characters with spaces

Comment: I didn't say to replace `\n` with `\r`. I said to check for that in addition to replacing `\n` with space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your input file has CRLF newlines. You need to ignore the CR characters when you're replacing LF with space. Otherwise, printing the CR characters will go back to the beginning of the line and overwrite what was already printed.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (c == '\n') {
            // replace newline with space
            putchar(' ');
        } else if (c == '\r') {
            // ignore CR
        } else {
            putchar(c);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Edited the code to both look for '\r' and '\n', so it may replace them properly! Another question: whenever I hit ENTER key in a txt file, will the end of that line be considered a newline character, a carriage return character, or both of them?

Comment: It depends on how the editor is configured, to use Unix or Windows newlines.